# how to fix object-fix image resize jumping

Tags: html, css, image, slider

I'm trying to work on a image slider in which you present an image with thumbnails underneath and when you click on the thumbnail, it shows another image. More like what you see in product detail page when they show different views of same product. Anyway, I'm trying to fit the image to the box's size so that no matter what the size is, the image fill up the width and height of the box. However, with the object-fix: cover, when I click on an thumbnail, the image seems squashed for a second before resizing to now. I've wondered if there's any other solutions that I can use to fix it?

In fact I tried to group the thumbnails under the images so that I can crop the images without constraining the images in another codepen example: http://codepen.io/kikibres/pen/yNGPQR but I couldn't get it to work...

Here's the one that's working but with resizing problem: http://codepen.io/kikibres/pen/xGmPpo

HTML

```
<div class="width">
<div class="slider">
    <input type="radio" name="slide_switch" id="id1"/>
    <label for="id1">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/9oFAr6F.jpg" />
    </label>
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/9oFAr6F.jpg"/>

    <!--Lets show the second image by default on page load-->
    <input type="radio" name="slide_switch" id="id2" checked="checked"/>
    <label for="id2">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/Q3DVhY0.jpg" />
    </label>
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/Q3DVhY0.jpg"/>


</div>

<!-- We will use PrefixFree - a script that takes care of CSS3 vendor prefixes
You can download it from http://leaverou.github.com/prefixfree/ -->
<script src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/js/prefixfree.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</div>
```

CSS

```
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
body {background: #ccc;}

.width { width: 600px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; margin: 100px auto;}

.slider{
    width: 100%; /*Same as width of the large image*/
  height: 300px;
    position: relative;

    /*Instead of height we will use padding*/
    /*padding-top: 320px; /*That helps bring the labels down*/

    /*Lets add a shadow*/
    box-shadow: 0 10px 20px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  border: 3px solid #000;
}


/*Last thing remaining is to add transitions*/
.slider>img{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; right: 0; top: 0;
    transition: all 0.5s;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: auto;
  /*max-height: 400px;
  max-width: 400px;*/
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.slider input[name='slide_switch'] {
    display: none;
}

.slider label {
    /*Lets add some spacing for the thumbnails*/
    margin: 18px 0 0 18px;
    border: 3px solid #999;

    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.5s;
  position: relative;
  top: 300px;
  left: 0;

    /*Default style = low opacity*/
    opacity: 0.6;
}

.slider label img{
    display: block;
  width: 80px;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

/*Time to add the click effects*/
.slider input[name='slide_switch']:checked+label {
    border-color: #666;
    opacity: 1;
}
/*Clicking any thumbnail now should change its opacity(style)*/
/*Time to work on the main images*/
.slider input[name='slide_switch'] ~ img {
    opacity: 0;
    /*transform: scale(1.1);*/
}
/*That hides all main images at a 110% size
On click the images will be displayed at normal size to complete the effect
*/
.slider input[name='slide_switch']:checked+label+img {
    opacity: 1;
    /*transform: scale(1);*/
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I commented out the

```
  transition: all 0.5s;
  overflow: auto;
```

in slider>img

and made it's max-height to 300px where it had been 100%

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGVadZ

Comment: So it was the transition that was causing the problem? thanks for your help! What are your thought on the other codepen that I create in which I grouped the images and thumbnails by themselves?

Comment: @KristinaBressler i couldn't get that other one to work??? but the output is  pretty much the same??

Comment: yeah I think. I just want to see if grouping the images and thumbnails by themselves will work. That way, one can have more control over the images without affecting the thumbnails.

Comment: If not, do you know of any other image slider with thumbnails tutorials that I can use that are responsive and pure css? I've been looking for one... The ones that comes close are this link: http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/css3-image-slider-with-stylized-thumbnails

Comment: I'm okay with jquery but try to use css as much as possible. Anyway what's the best jquery for what I'm looking for?